# Is this a defect in the `/SUBSYSTEM (Specify subsystem)`, a MS document?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, linker

The /SUBSYSTEM = CONSOLE linker option is described under the section **CONSOLE** in this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019), as follows:

> Win32 character-mode application. The operating system provides a
>   console for console applications. If `main` or `wmain` is defined for
>   native code, `int main(array<String ^> ^)` is defined for managed
>   code, or you build the application completely by using `/clr:safe`,
>   `CONSOLE` is the default.

I thus conclude that an assembly (a native code) that doesn't provide a /SUBSYSTEM, but supplies an /ENTRY = `main` or `wmain` is built using a `CONSOLE` by default. I can confirm this for the code below,

```
.386
.MODEL flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO STDCALL, dwExitCode: DWORD

.CODE
main PROC
    mov eax, -1
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

END main
```

by running DUMPBIN for the corresponding executable where I get this output, which confirms the paragraph above, according to [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#windows-subsystem) in the PE Format document.

[image]

The same should apply for the /SUBSYSTEM = WINDOWS, as described under the section **WINDOWS**, as follows:

> Application does not require a console, probably because it creates
>   its own windows for interaction with the user. If `WinMain` or
>   `wWinMain` is defined for native code, or `WinMain(HISTANCE *, HINSTANCE *, char *, int)` or
>   `wWinMain(HINSTANCE *, HINSTANCE *, wchar_t *, int)` is defined for managed code, `WINDOWS` is the
>   default.

But when I try to build the assembly code below without a /SUBSYSTEM option, but with /ENTRY = `WinMain` the linker emits the following error: `LNK1221: a subsystem can't be inferred and must be defined`.

```
.386
.MODEL flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO STDCALL, dwExitCode: DWORD

.CODE
WinMain PROC
    mov eax, -1
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
WinMain ENDP

END WinMain
```

I must then conclude that there is a defect in the alluded Microsoft document in relation to the /SUBSYSTEM = Windows. Or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I introduced this edit section in response to the answer given by Ross Ridge below.

These are build simulations that I have done for all possible scenarios

[image]

to show that the term *defined* used in the following sentences in [/SUBSYSTEM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019) mean to be defined in the /ENTRY option, not in the source or .obj files.

1. "If `main` or `wmain` is defined for native code ..." in the **Console** subsection
2. If `WinMain`or `wWinMain` is defined for native code ..." in the **Windows** subsection

of the alluded MS document.

Thus, it seems to me, there is nothing wrong with my first example, simply because the other cases don't even build.

**EDIT1**

I still don't understand why do I need to erase the entry point at the END directive. Could you explain this? Nevertheless, after doing this erasure, I still have some differences in relation to your results, as you can see below.

[image]

Surprisingly, you were able to build the last case above, where I continue with a linker error.

Comment: The whole entry-point name thing is probably just for the compiler, which then invokes the linker accordingly. It is documented in the linker because it's the one having those options, I guess.

Comment: If you specify the `/SUBSYSTEM=Windows` option, does the second example link and run correctly?

Comment: @prl Of course it does,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first inference is not quite correct. It's not whether the entry point is named `main` or `wmain` but whether either of these symbols are defined by any of the object files being linked.  Normally these symbols are not used as the entry point of a console application, the default entry point for a console application is actually `mainCRTStartup` or `wmainCRTStartup`.  These entry points are defined by the Microsoft C runtime, and will call `main` or `wmain` respectively after initializing the C runtime library.

The problem in the second example is that you haven't declared `WinMain` correctly.  This function is a part of the Windows API and so uses same "stdcall" calling convention most other 32-bt x86 Windows API functions use.  In this calling convention symbol names are prefixed with an underscore `_` and suffixed with `@#` where `#` is the size in bytes of the arguments passed to the function.  Since the Windows API defines `WinMain` as a function taking 4 arguments that take up 16 bytes on the stack, the linker is looking to see if the symbol `_WinMain@16` is defined. Since your definition of `WinMain` doesn't have any arguments, your code ends up defining the symbol `_WinMain@0` instead

Note, strictly speaking the `main` in your first example should having been defined using the "cdecl" calling convention instead of stdcall.  This would cause the assembler to use the symbol `_main` instead of the symbol `_main@0`.  In the cdecl calling convention symbol names are prefixed with `_` and don't have a suffix added.  Because you gave `main` as entry point the linker was able to figure this out.  When creating 32-bit x86 images, this underscore `_` prefix, but not any `@#` suffix, is also necessary for all the other symbols I mentioned in the first paragraph: `_main`, `_mainCRTStartup`, `_wmainCRTStartup`.

For 64-bit x86 targets, both `main` and `WinMain` use same x64 calling convention, and this convention doesn't add prefixes or suffixes to symbols, so it's just `main`, `WinMain`, `mainCRTStartup`, etc.

Personally, I would recommend specifying the subsystem you want explicitly with the `/SUBSYSTEM:` option.  I would strongly recommend not using an entry point named `main` or `WinMain` as this would imply that these functions are supposed to be the standard C or Windows API functions of the same name when in fact they aren't.

---

To prove what I said in the first paragraph, I've run the same tests as you claim to have run. This is the assembly file I used to perform the test:

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
M   PROC
    int 3
M   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS

    END
```

And here are the commands I ran:

```
ml /DM=main t450.asm /link /entry:main
ml /DM=main t450.asm
ml /DM=_main t450.asm /link /entry:_main
ml /DM=_main t450.asm
ml /DM=main t450.asm /link /entry:_main
ml /DM=_main t450.asm /link /entry:main
```

And here are the results I got:

```
> ml /DM=main t450.asm /link /entry:main 
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/OUT:t450.exe 
t450.obj 
/entry:main 
 Assembling: t450.asm

> ml /DM=main t450.asm 
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/OUT:t450.exe 
t450.obj 
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
 Assembling: t450.asm

> ml /DM=_main t450.asm /link /entry:_main 
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/OUT:t450.exe 
t450.obj 
/entry:_main 
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __main
t450.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
 Assembling: t450.asm

> ml /DM=_main t450.asm 
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/OUT:t450.exe 
t450.obj 
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
t450.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
 Assembling: t450.asm

> ml /DM=main t450.asm /link /entry:_main 
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/OUT:t450.exe 
t450.obj 
/entry:_main 
LINK : fatal error LNK1221: a subsystem can't be inferred and must be defined
 Assembling: t450.asm

> ml /DM=_main t450.asm /link /entry:main 
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/OUT:t450.exe 
t450.obj 
/entry:main 
 Assembling: t450.asm
```

Summarizing the results:

```
 /ENTRY    Defined   Result
 main      main      No error
 Not set   main      LNK1561: entry point must be defined
 _main     _main     LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __main
 Not set   _main     LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
 _main     main      LNK1221: a subsystem can't be inferred and must be defined
 main      _main     No error
```

None of these results are inconsistent with what I said above, although we do learn that the linker automatically prefixes the symbol passed with the /ENTRY command line option with an underscore `_`.

I've left out tests related to `WinMain` as I don't know what you're trying to prove with that. Suffice to say though that I've also verified that defining `_WinMain@16` as explained above does allow the linker to infer a subsystem.

Comment: See my **Edit** section above.

Comment: @Belloc if your edit was meant to refute my answer, then I'm afraid you're wrong.  I don't know how you obtained your results, but I can't reproduce them. I performed the same tests as you and got different results.  My guess is that part of the problem is that you're still defining an entry point with the END directive, which functions identically as the /ENTRY switch.

Comment: See my **Edit1** above

Comment: @Belloc You're not showing how you're producing the results you get so I can only guess as to why they're still different. This time, my guess is that you're using `.model stdcall` which causes the assembler to automatically add the `_` prefix and `@#` suffix to function names, so the real symbols you're defining are `_main@0` and `__main@0`.  The linker is able to do some fuzzy matching sometimes, ignoring `_` prefixes and `@#` suffixes, in order to match up symbols,  so "the linker was able to figure this out" and match `/entry:main`, with `_main@0`.

Comment: @Belloc I've updated my answer to account for the fact that you were using `.model flat, stdcall` in your examples, which I hadn't noticed before. This however doesn't change any of my conclusions.

Comment: Great answer. After a lot of research on the topic at hand, I think I am now better prepared to gauge the quality of your answer.. Thank you.